# How should I set up these tables for searching?

Tags: mysql, search, locking, innodb, myisam

My PHP site is an online store with about 5k products. Products belong to a vendor, a category, and possibly a subcategory. Each of those items has a name and the products have descriptions.

The search queries we've set up work wonderfully, but tend to run pretty slow. They range between 0.20s and 30s (yes 30 seconds). We've optimized like crazy and I'm starting to think we're out of room to improve on that front, so we're caching them and that's making life a lot easier.

But when they run they are still killing the server, because what appears to be all of the table locking that comes with MyISAM.

So on to my question: **Is there a way for us to use InnoDB (row-level locking) and still maintain FULLTEXT? Should we move our DB offsite and use a service like DB2? Is there some other search engine type software we should use instead?**

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB does have full-text indexing now: http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/innodb-full-text-search-tutorial/

but since it's basically brand new, most MySQL installs will not support it yet.

The standard workaround is to have a 'mirror' MyISAM table that contains copies of the searchable data with a fulltext index. You then join the original InnoDB table against the MyISAM copies, with fulltext searches on the myisam fields and regular other 'where' clauses on the innodb copies.

With appropriate triggers on the InnoDB table, there's no reason that the MyISAM copies would get stale/incorrect, or you could simply rebuild them on a scheduled basis so that you've got a staleness window that matches the rebuild interval.